# bootstrap check/uncheck multiple elements with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make this work but can't make it happen. I have a bootstrap template and i want to check and uncheck multiple checkboxes (like this: http://jsfiddle.net/v6wmV/177/ )
I know this is a common subject with many solutions, but none seem to work for this case and i would like to know why.

**This is the code snippet from the view:**

```
<div class="hide" id="states">
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Select</label>
    <div class="check">
    <div class="controls">
        <label class="checkbox line">
            <input type="checkbox" class="all" value="Todas" id="allstates" name="st[25]"/>All
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox line">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Caba" id="" name="st[1]"/>Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox line">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Buenos Aires" id="" name="st[2]"/> Buenos Aires
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox line">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Catamarca" id="" name="st[3]"/> Catamarca
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox line">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Chaco" id="" name="st[4]"/> Chaco
        </label>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**and this is my js file (with other functions):**

```
$('.hide').hide();

$('#registered').click(function(){
 $('#content').toggle('fast');
});

$('#age').click(function () {
$('#content2').hide('fast');
$('#content1').show('fast');
});

$('#range').click(function () {
$('#content1').hide('fast');
$('#content2').show('fast');
});

$('#with').click(function(){
$('#child').toggle('fast');
});

$('#showstates').click(function(){
$('#states').show('fast');
});

$('#hidestates').click(function(){
$('#states').hide('fast');
});

//function for check/uncheck
$('.all').click(function() {
var $checkboxes = $(this).parent().find('input[type=checkbox]');
$checkboxes.prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

this is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jimena/j56Dy/
which is not working

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/g3mu8/185/

Comment: use parents() instead of parent http://jsbin.com/eCOrUtO/1/

Comment: @Joe yes, like that but not with a button, just with another checkbox

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g3mu8/188/ ??

Comment: @Joe yes, like that. Check the code on fiddle, is still not working: http://jsfiddle.net/jimena/j56Dy/

Comment: @Manish i use parents() now, but there is no difference, still not working. I am suspecting there is something to do with the hide function...

Comment: @Jimena are the checkboxes visible? coz you have  $('.hide').hide(); that is hiding the div

Comment: @Manish they are only visible when the user choose to "select states". So when he presses it, the html i posted shows. That is why i put the hide class

Comment: @Jimena if you are talking about your fiddle ,the top part of the code is missing check the fiddle. after changing the code is working

Comment: @Manish now i updated the code and it's totally working, even included the code you said it was missing :) http://jsfiddle.net/jimena/j56Dy/6/

Answer (score 0):

you need to go up two stages instead of one. parent() gives you the label element, you need to go up to the "controls"-classed div to apply your find method :

var $checkboxes = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type=checkbox]');

Of course that was to apply minimal change to your code way. The one provided by Joe up here is probably smarter : getting all the checkboxes you want without having to use parent() method. But to do so you might want to id your checkbox group so that you do not select all the checkboxes accross your DOM.

By the way, don't you have to show your hide div at some point to see your checkboxes ?

Edit> OK actually Manish is right with parents it is just right, forget my answer :D

Comment: yes, i have to show my hide div but only when the users press to show it. After showing the content, the user should have the possibility to check multiple checkboxes and the possibility to check all a time, like i am trying to do now :)

Comment: did you try to go up two elements instead of one ? because a find on the label cannot work. I reckon that within jsfiddle this is not working (except by Joe's way) but it might be some weird conflict on symbols I guess

Comment: OK actually Manish is right with parents... just you missed to activate jquery in your fiddle. Here you go : http://jsfiddle.net/j56Dy/2/

Comment: you are so right, thanks for the tip, now it is working, check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jimena/j56Dy/6/

Comment: Be careful that if you have several groups that all have their own "Toggle All" checkbox, using parents() like that will return all the checkboxes, so your code will trigger all the page checkboxes. You might want to use .parent("div"), but that's depend how you build yours groups I believe. http://jsfiddle.net/j56Dy/3/

Comment: the code is really working on fiddle, but i don't know why it is not working on my site