# my code doesn't work with the script i am calling from the base file

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have previously posted this: [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520252/bootstrap-check-uncheck-multiple-elements-with-js) about having problems to check and uncheck multiple elements with jquery.

The thing is that i have tried the code on fiddle and it's working perfect thanks to all the people who helped me: [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jimena/j56Dy/8/) but it is not working on my site.

I have a base.php that automatically loads core plugins, script and so... it's even calling:

```
<script src="{site_url()}assets/plugins/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

from the view file, i call the js function i use like this: (i use smarty template)

```
{block name='custom_javascript'}
<script src="{site_url()}assets/scripts/backend/filter-options.js"></script> 
{/block}
```

The thing is that the check/uncheck function is not working. It only works when i call (again) the jquery library like this:

```
{block name='custom_javascript'}
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="{site_url()}assets/scripts/backend/filter-options.js"></script> 
{/block}
```

even though it works, the style is not the same, because boxes and text appear not in line.

Am i doing something wrong with the library or what the problem could be? thanks on advance.

Comment: Errors? Code? Do you use Firebug to watch your javascript console for issues?

Comment: Did you modify the CSS of the various elements?

Comment: @cale_b without calling again to <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> i have no errors in my console

Comment: @JustinWood no i didn't. Did not touch any css

Comment: Definitely consider using CSS for the style and format of your site. also you might consider trying the fire fox web developer to edit the CSS while you view it in the browser once you do that just copy past into the code.

Comment: @CS_STEM thnx for the tip, i use chrome and the tools it offers. I didn't touch any css, but it is weird that only after adding the link to the online jquery library the function works. Despite it works the console shows an error

Comment: What does the source of your page look like? It appears that in your base template, your jQuery library is loading AFTER your `filter_options.js` (and jQuery is required by `filter_options.js`) Under no circumstances should you declare jQuery twice (same or different versions) on the same page.

Comment: @Adam my base.php is adapted to my site, the template says: Load javascripts at bottom, this will reduce page load time. But in my view file i call to my function on the top

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, the problem is that your scripts are getting loaded like this:

```
<!-- page -->
...template header (from base.php)


...your template code
<script src="...filter_options.js"></script> <-- coming from your template



...template footer (from base.php)
<script src="...jquery"></script> <-- coming from base.php
```

So from this you can see that jQuery does not get loaded until AFTER your script. The problem here is that your script (`filter_options.js`) depends on jQuery and requires it to be loaded before it can be used.

I would move the jQuery script to the head of your base.php. Ideally, you would move the jQuery script to the head, and leave all other scripts in the footer. This gives you the benefit of always knowing you have jQuery available for use, no matter where you place scripts in your template files.

Comment: My base.php has some core files that are loaded at the beginning. So, my jquery-1.10.1 is always loaded. What is at the botton is the calling for "custom javascripts". From the different views, i call to my custom javascripts at the top.

Comment: anyway, i loaded the library at the top of my base.php. It works fine with other js functions from the page, but the function i made to checkall doesn' work.